# How to multiply each 2D element of a tensor with dynamic dimension by a static 2D mask?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, keras

I have an input Tensor of size (?, 64, 64) and a static Tensor mask of size (64, 64).
I want the output tensor of this model to be of shape (?, 64, 64) where the i_th element of the output is an element by element multiplication of the i_th element of the input and the mask.

I've tried using the Multiply() layer in keras, as it provides an element by element multiplication, but it outputs a tensor of (64, 64, 64). I've now read that Multiply() expects tensors to be of the same dimension, which explains my problem.

I then figured I could create a tensor of shape (?, 64, 64) made by concatenating ? copies of the mask and then use Multiply(). I can't create this tensor, however, because I don't have the value of ?. (I try using Img.shape[0], but it gives me an error since it is a NoneType)

I also decided to change the values of the tensor element by element with something like:
rFD1 = K.zeros_like(img)
rFD1[:, ::2, ::2] = img[:, ::2, ::2]
But I get an error saying tensorflow doesn't support item assignment (how is this not an issue for people?!).

I've read so many threads about it, but none of them have solved my problem yet.

```
def MyFunc(img):
    rmask = np.zeros([64, 64])
    rmask[::2, ::2] = np.ones([32, 32])
    rmask = K.variable(rmask)
    rFD1 = Multiply()([img, rmask])

    return rFD1

img = Input(shape = (64, 64))
x1 = Lambda(MyFunc)(img)
model = Model(input = img, output = x1)
model.summary()
```

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_99 (InputLayer)        (None, 64, 64)            0

lambda_720 (Lambda)          (64, 64, 64)              0

Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0

Where I expect an Output Shape of (None, 64, 64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `Multiply` layer, you can use the * operator, [which broadcasts](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9042):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Multiply, Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
```

```py
def MyFunc(img):
    rmask = np.zeros([64, 64])
    rmask[::2, ::2] = np.ones([32, 32])
    rmask = K.variable(rmask)
    rFD1 = img * rmask

    return rFD1

img = Input(shape = (64, 64))
x1 = Lambda(MyFunc)(img)
model = Model(input = img, output = x1)
model.summary()
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         (None, 64, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_6 (Lambda)            (None, 64, 64)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Check that everything works:

```py
test_image = K.constant(5., shape=(64,64))
y = model(test_image)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(y.eval() )
    print(y.shape)
```

```
[[5. 0. 5. ... 0. 5. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [5. 0. 5. ... 0. 5. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [5. 0. 5. ... 0. 5. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
(64, 64)
```

Comment: You sir, are the best... Thank you!